# Problem with TinyMCE on Wicket when using addOrReplace

Tags: java, html, tinymce, wicket

I have a class, let's say MyRichTextEditor that becomes enriched via TinyMCESettings.

Iside a form, there are 2 fields that use MyRichEditor components. When submitting the form, I want to repaint these components using the addOrReplace() method.  However, after the ajax request, no rich text is on the page. Instead, the initial textArea fields are shown.

MyRichEditorClass.java

```
public class MyRichTextEditor extends TextArea<String> {

    protected TinyMCESettings settings;
    private boolean showToolbar;
    private boolean readOnly;

    public MyRichTextEditor(String id, boolean showToolbar, boolean readOnly) {

        super(id);
        this.showToolbar = showToolbar;
        this.readOnly = readOnly;
        settings = new TinyMCESettings(TinyMCESettings.Theme.modern);
        settings.addCustomSetting("content_style: \"body { font-family: Verdana,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; }\"");
        addSettings();
        add(new TinyMceBehavior(settings));

    }

    public MyRichTextEditor(String id) {

        this(id, true, false);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {

        super.onInitialize();
        add(AttributeAppender.append("class", "my-rich-text-editor"));
        if (getModelObject() == null) {
            setModelObject("Insert your text here");
        }

    }

    protected void addSettings() {

        settings.setMenuBar(false);
        settings.addCustomSetting("force_p_newlines : true");
        settings.addCustomSetting("force_br_newlines : true");
        settings.addCustomSetting("convert_newlines_to_brs : false");
        settings.addCustomSetting("remove_linebreaks : true");

        if (showToolbar) {
            //@formatter:off
                String plugins = "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak "
                        + "searchreplace  visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime "
                        + "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage colorpicker";

                // @formatter:on  
            String[] pluginNames = plugins.split(" ");

            for (String name : pluginNames) {
                settings.addPlugins(name);
            }

            settings.addToolbar(
                new Toolbar(
                    "toolbar1",
                    "newdocument | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect"));
            settings.addToolbar(
                new Toolbar(
                    "toolbar2",
                    "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor code | inserttime preview | forecolor backcolor"));
            settings.addToolbar(
                new Toolbar(
                    "toolbar3",
                    "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap emoticons | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | nonbreaking  restoredraft"));

            settings.addCustomSetting("readonly : " + (readOnly ? "1" : "0"));

        } else {
            settings.addCustomSetting("readonly:1");
            settings.addCustomSetting("toolbar:false");

        }

    }

}
```

MyPanel.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<body>
<wicket:panel>
    <wicket:extend>
        <form wicket:id="form">

            .
            .
            .

            
            <wicket:label for="description">Request Description</wicket:label>
            <textarea wicket:id="description"></textarea>
           

                
            <wicket:label for="response">Response</wicket:label>
            <textarea wicket:id="response"></textarea>
                


            .
            .
            .

        </form>


    </wicket:extend>
</wicket:panel>

</body>
</html>
```

MyPanel.java

```
class EpikAitimaKentrikisDiacheirisisPanel extends ...{

    ...

    TextArea<String> description, response;


    AjaxSubmitLink btnSave;

    
    @Override
    protected void onInitialize() {

        super.onInitialize();

        form = new CompoundPropertyModelForm<>("form", modelObject);
        add(form);

                ...

        paintDescriptionAndResponseComponents();

        

        btnSave = new AjaxSubmitLink("btnSave"){

            @Override
            protected void οnSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                btnSaveOnSubmit(target);

            }

        };
        btnSave.add(new TinyMceAjaxSubmitModifier());
        form.add(btnSave);

    }

    private void btnSaveOnSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

        form.getModelObject().setDescription(org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils.htmlUnescape(description.getModelObject()));

        //save form.getModelObject
                //reload saved object

        paintDescriptionAndResponseComponents();

        target.add(form);

    }

    

    private void paintDescriptionAndResponseComponents() {

        description= new MyRichTextEditor("description", showDescriptionToolbar(), descriptionReadOnly());
        description.add(Validators.required());
        description.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        form.addOrReplace(description);

        response= new MyRichTextEditor("response", showResponseToolbar(), responseReadOnly());
        response.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        response.add(Validators.required());
        form.addOrReplace(response);

    }

    private boolean reponseReadOnly() {

        ...
    }

    private boolean showResponseToolbar() {

        ...
    }

    private boolean descriptionReadOnly() {

        ...

    }

    private boolean showDescriptionToolbar() {

        ...

    }

}
```